# copy the lines of a file into hashmap in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a file with multiple lines. In each line, there two words and a number, split by a comma - for example a, b, 1. It means that string A and string B have the key as 1. I wrote the below piece of code

```
File.open(ARGV[0], 'r') do |f1|  
  while line = f1.gets  
    puts line  
  end  
end
```

i'm looking for an idea of how to split and copy the characters and number in such a way that the first two words have the last number as key in the hashmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
hash = {}
File.readlines(ARGV[0]).each do |line|
     var = line.gsub(' ','').split(',')
     hash[var[2]] = var[0],var[1]
end
```

This would give:

```
hash['1'] = ['a','b']
```

I don't know if you want to store number one as an integer or a string, if it's a integer you're looking for, just do `var[2].to_i` before storing.

Modified your code a little bit, i think it's shorter this way, if i'm in any way wrong, do let me know.

Comment: hi, acutally the new line '\n' is also being copied and now it is looking like {"1\n"=>["a", "b"]}. I need to remove then \n too. any idea?

Comment: oh, sorry, before storing you could do `var[2].chop` or if you're storing it as an integer the `.to_i` method will handle it by itself.